# add icon to html code title

Tags: html, title

This is  not a favicon as others  had corrected  another post.

This is  how Expedia  page source  code looks:

```
<title data-sctid="title" data-sct-hidden="true"> Atlantic City Hotels: Find 122 Cheap Hotel Deals in Atlantic City, NJ | Expedia</title>
```

the  result page in  google  shows this http://goo.gl/YEjujq

I tried to insert   into

```
  $this->set('title_for_layout', " Atlantic City Hotels: 28 Cheap Hotel Deals AtlanticCity.com");
```

but  can not save  since I get this  error

> Text encoding Western (ISO Latin 1) isn’t applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because this character is (probably) not part of the Latin 1 code page. you should encode your page in Unicode (UTF-8 is what's usually being used) for it to work.

Comment: ok..  tried  this....     "&#9734; Atlantic City Hotels: 28 Cheap Hotel Deals AtlanticCity.com");          a star.... will see if  it shows in  google.    found that here  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols      couldnt  find   nice colored one like they have

Comment: ok...   i found the  source. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs

Answer (score 1):

Just as Tsahi says, that character is not valid in that particular encoding.

What you **can** do, is try its unicode or html character codes:

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', "&#127976; Atlantic City Hotels...
```

or

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', "\uD83C\uDFE8 Atlantic City Hotels...
```

Comment: i tried the latter, and it worked.  `$("input[name='q']").value = "\uD83C\uDFE8 Atlantic City"`